# What are the various ways of improving indexing on ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-configuration, aws-elasticsearch

I'm using ELK to process and monitor log files of considerable size. I am pushing logs from the local file system.

But I am facing several issues:

1. Parsing using LogStash is very slow due to the large size of data. It gets slower with an increase in filter plugins. (It's taken over 4 days for 3.2GB of logs!)
2. Making API calls and building visualizations in Kibana over these indices is slow too.

How can I solve these issues?

1. Move to cloud solutions: AWS or Google Cloud? But these might entail
   added costs.
2. Improving indexing techniques. How can I achieve this in ES?

Any help would be beneficial. Thanks!

ETA:

My logstash config:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/home/adb/data/**/**/*.gz" #path to subfolder (2nd level) containing .gz files
        mode => "read"
        file_completed_action => "log"
        file_completed_log_path => "/home/adb/data/log.txt"
    }
}

filter {
    csv {
        separator => "&"
        columns => ["T", "D", "CID", "RT", "RP" ...]
    }

    kv {
        source => "RP"
        target => "RP"
        value_split => "#"
        field_split => "*"
    }

    mutate {
        split => { "RT" => "*" }
    }

    date {
                match => ["T", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
                timezone => "UTC"
                target => "ET"
        }

     mutate {
                convert => {
                        "RT" => "integer"
                }
        }

}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost"
        index => "trial1"
        document_type => "A_C"
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

Comment: How are you parsing in logstash ? Can you post logstash config ? How does your index setting look like ? What is the shard configuration ? I'd highly recommend looking at Elastic Cloud (https://www.elastic.co/cloud/elasticsearch-service), their pricing is decent too. To improve indexing performance, suggest looking at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-indexing-speed.html. Especially look at disabling refresh as it improves indexing performance significantly.

Comment: Visualizations in Kibana can be slow if you are doing heavy aggregations or if your cluster is under load. Look at your resource usage, is it sufficient ?

Comment: @ben5556 I'm new to ELK Stack ... so I haven't made any index setting or shard configs yet. I'm using a generic CPU as of now. Haven't put it on a dedicated server system, yet.

Comment: we used to use logstash 2-2.5 years back. It was memory hungry and slow, as far as I remember. Moved to java based app to do the parsing, and never looked back. Although it's true that our use case also changed over the time.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing may be slow when have large size of data with logstash while elastic search indexing. You can put apache kafka between your applications and logstash to speed up indexing.

Comment: Kafka seems to be an added dependency here. Could be useful in a long-term production environ, though.

Comment: we have used kafka for our production environment. Just check,https://www.elastic.co/blog/just-enough-kafka-for-the-elastic-stack-part1